# How to build and upload a correctly signed iOS app to App Store

Tags: xcode, cordova

I have a Cordova iOS app that works fine in the ios simulator. Time to give it to external testers.

At the Apple Developer portal, I created the appropriate *iOS Distribution* certificate named 'Pathway Productions Inc.', App ID, and *iOS Distribution* provisioning profile named 'Beta test'.

At iTunes Connect, I created the appropriate App Record (name: 'StressRelief'; bundle ID: 'com.goodsexnetwork.StressRelief').

In Xcode, I configured 'Signing (Release)' with the 'Beta test' Provisioning Profile and the 'Pathway Productions Inc.' Signing Certificate. The Team is 'Pathway Productions Inc.'.

In build.json:

```
{
    "ios": {
        "debug": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "provisioningProfile": "",
            "developmentTeam": "",
            "packageType": "development"
        },
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
            "provisioningProfile": "UDID from Beta_test.mobileprovision",
            "developmentTeam": "",
            "packageType": "ad-hoc"
        }
    }
}
```

I took the 'provisioningProfile' from the UDID in the Beta_test.mobileprovision file.

When I build the .ipa application file with this command,

```
cordova build --release --device --buildConfig
```

it is successful. Now to upload it (platforms/ios/build/device/StressRelief.ipa) to Apple for review using the Application Loader...

It fails with this error message:

**ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.goodsexnetwork.StressRelief [Payload/StressRelief.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.] A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."**

Um, no, there is a code-signing certificate. It's named 'Pathway Productions Inc.' and it is correctly configured in Xcode. So what is the *real* problem?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time I get
It wasn't detecting my provision profile automatically. I found it specifying with xcode and reading it on notepad.

You also must specify development team.
Here is a link to Cordova build.json specification: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/

Here is a tip to configure hooks: https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html

You must specify all items:

```
"release": {
  "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
  "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "packageType": "app-store"
}
```